# moment inequality of martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, martingales

Let $M_t$ be a martingale whose quadratic variation is finite (and also any higher moments).

Then for any $s<t$ and $k > 1$, is it true that
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}|M_s|^k \le \mathbb{E}|M_t|^k?
\end{align*}

My intuition says that due to the quadratic variation of any martingale is increasing, so $\mathbb{E}|M_s|^2 \le \mathbb{E}|M_t|^k$ is quite trivial due to the Ito's isometry.
But is this still hold for any arbitrary $k>1$?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't it true in general that if $Y=\Bbb E(X|A)$ then $\Bbb E|Y|^k\le\Bbb E|X|^k$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$|M_s| \leq E(|M_t| \, |\mathcal F_s)$ and $f(x)=x^{k}$ is an increasing convex function on $[0,\infty)$ Hence, $|M_s|^{k} \leq (E(|M_t|\mathcal F_s))^{k} \leq E(|M_t|^{k}\mathcal F_s)$ by Jensen's inequality. Take expectation on both sides.